# DataTable is not a function. Missing import?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm getting the following **error** when I run my view page when debugging in JavaScript.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (GetTvShow:59)
at e (jquery.min.js:2)
at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Is it because I'm missing an Import? I'm not able to figure this simple ajax call.

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "GetTvShow";
 }
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <h1>AddShow</h1>
 <html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt- 
1.10.20/datatables.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.js"> 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTable1').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/GetAllMovie",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Id" },
                { "data": "Title" }

            ]
        });
    });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container py-4">

    <div id="dataTable_wrapper"></div>
    <table id="dataTable1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

From my controller I'm passing the correct Json data
Controller returning data:

```
 return Json(TvShowList,new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
```

Comment: do you have any other errors loading datatables?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked for me, though I made one change.

I changed

```
 "columns": [
                { "data": "Id" },
                { "data": "Title" }

            ]
```

to

```
 columns: [
            { title: "Id" },
            { title: "Title" }
```

I also have a JSFiddle, but I modified your Ajax Request to use a json object I had grabbed from the online dataTable examples: https://jsfiddle.net/menelaosbgr/Lphbd5a0/3/

See also: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array

Try also to change your ajax request - I think you don't need those extra params. In their example where they read json data, they only use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable1').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '/GetAllMovie'
    } );
} );
```

E.g. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax